# Cannot download flipmaxdiff from the github respository

Tags: r

I am setting up coding in R to analyze maxdiff data using the following guide:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-analyze-max-diff-data-in-r/

This require to install flipmaxdiff package using install_github("Displayr/flipMaxDiff")

But it is giving me following error:
Error: HTTP error 404.
  Not Found

Rate limit remaining: 14/60
  Rate limit reset at: 2019-04-15 14:27:05 UTC

Can anyone help me with downloading this package or recommend anyother way I can complete my maxdiff analysis?

Thanks,

Zahir

Answer (score 0):

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("Displayr/flipData")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've already installed this package but the rest of the code require displayr/flipmaxdiff to be installed in the system, which I could not download. It seem like the github package does not exist anymore.